# Java - Convert input String including integers into Set of integers

Tags: java

I want to input string like these :
`[4, 5, 6] + [1, 2, 3]`

`[1, 1, 12] - [22, 12, 0]`
...

How do I put all the integers in each brackets [] in to a set. 
Ex: result will be two sets

`[4, 5, 6] and [1, 2, 3]`
`[1, 1, 12] and [22, 12, 0]`

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: I have tried this by converting it into char array. But the problem It only can convert the number from 0 to 9. With all the numbers that have more than 2 digits (>10), it does not work.

Comment: Please be more specific and clear.

Comment: `Input string: 

[11, 23, 1, 4] + [2, 3, 6, 1]
Result: 

[1, 2, 3, 4] and
[1, 2, 3, 6]`

Comment: As my purpose, the result must be [11, 23, 1, 4] instead of [1, 2, 3, 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it answers your question, you might be trying to do this:

```
    String input = "[4, 5, 6] + [1, 2, 3]" ;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()){
        Set<Integer> S = new TreeSet<>();
        String g = m.group(1);
        Stream.of(g.split(",")).forEach(i -> S.add(Integer.parseInt(i.trim())));    
        System.out.println(S);
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could us a regexp expression to extract the `[]` tokens from the input string (you can use [regexplanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to test/validate the regexp)). Then you could use the string tokenizer to create sets of the retrieved tokens. So the program would look on high level as follows:

```
// Set containing subsets which contain integer values between []
Set<Set> sets = new HashSet();

String  in = "[4, 5, 6] + [1, 2, 3] [1, 1, 12] - [22, 12, 0]";

// Get all tokens between []
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(...).matcher(in);
while ( matcher.find() ) {

    Set<int> subSet = new HashSet();
    sets.add(subSet);

    // Get integer values between []
    String values = matcher.group();

    // Add all integers to subset
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(values, ",");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
       subset.add(st.nextToken());
    }
}
```

*NOTE:* I haven't tested nor compiled the code above so it might be faulty and there might be more optimal ways to do it!